# How to reset standard dupefilter in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

For some reasons I would like to reset the list of seen urls that `scrapy` maintains internally at some point of my spider code.

I know that by default scrapy uses the [`RFPDupeFilter`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L28) class and that there is a `fingerprint` set.

How can this set be cleared within spider code?

To be more specific: I'd like to clear the set in a custom `idle_handler` method that is called by a `spider_idle` signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current `dupefilter` object used by the spider via `self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df`.

```
from scrapy import signals, Spider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher


class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "example"
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        dispatcher.connect(self.reset_dupefilter, signals.spider_idle)

    def reset_dupefilter(self, spider):
        # clear stored fingerprints by the dupefilter when idle
        self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df.fingerprints = set()

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the fingerprint set by initializing fingerprints

```
    self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df.fingerprints = set()
```

to an empty set.
Put the following code in your spider.

```
    def reset_filter(self, spider):
        self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df.fingerprints = set()

    #overriding the default from_crawler class method to access scrapy core components
    @classmethod    
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        #initiate an event signal when spider is idle
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.reset_filter, signals.spider_idle)
        return spider
```

please refer to https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762 for more information.